# Translucent Status Bar and ListView issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And it looks like this

[Link to example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IefqW.jpg)

But i want my list was under the status bar.
Like in Google Photo app

[Link to example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJhyJ.jpg)

I added `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to my ListView but got no desired result.

Please help me to achieve ListView behavior like in Google Photo.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView has nothing to do with transparent status bar.

If you want your app to have a transparent status bar, you need to implement your style like this

```
<!-- Make the status bar translucent -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"> <!-- or some theme you are using-->
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Then in your Activity,

```
// A method to find height of the status bar
public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }

    return height;
}

// in your onCreate
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    // Retrieve the AppCompact Toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Set the padding to match the Status Bar height
    toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);
}
```

Most source is from : http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/04/11/android-and-the-transparent-status-bar.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following to style your activity is using (will only work on api level 21 or later though)

```
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```